# How much polysilcon is required to make 1GW of solar modules?

Tags: solar

Could anyone give me a good anwser here,  even an approximation?

Comment: "About 5 tons of polysilicon is required to manufacture one 1 megawatt (MW) conventional solar modules" source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycrystalline_silicon)

Comment: Polysilicon is not a limiting resource in any way. You can get silicon from sand. The limiting resource is silver.